# Has anyone heard of a Python 2.7 package called ut?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I am currently installing the ImageJ package for `Python=2.7`. I keep getting the error:

`from operator import add`

`---> from ut.ml.sk.feature_extraction.text import TreeTokenizer`

`from functools import reduce`

`ImportError: No module named ut.ml.sk.feature_extraction.text`.

I have Googled and used conda search ut to find this module, and I haven't been able to dig up any information on it. Does anyone know where I can find more information on this module, or even better, know how to install it using pip/conda? Thank you all so much!

EDIT: The ImageJ Jython plugin for Python is only documented for Python 2.7 as stated in the docs [here](https://imagej.net/scripting/jython/). Therefor, I cannot update to Python 3.x if I want to use this plugin.

Comment: Is it possible that it is just a mirror of SciKit learn library. sk is short for scikit learn?

Comment: Not answering your question.  But every month there's something new that stops working or stops being supported in Python 2.7.   You're really better off switching to Python 3

Comment: Python 2.7 is no longer supported.

Comment: Here is a page on ImageJ and python: https://imagej.net/scripting/python. It could be that this has to run on jython and that this is a java package.

Comment: @PeterWood - In this case, I don't think there is a lot of choice. This looks like a jython binding to the Java based ImageJ and jython is still python 2.x.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps this is what you're after: https://github.com/thorwhalen/ut

Although the readme isn't very helpful

> Miscellaneous Personal Utility functions.

It does define a class that matches the import statement exactly:

[`ut.ml.sk.feature_extraction.text.TreeTokenizer`](https://github.com/thorwhalen/ut/blob/5fe0e7031d4c66a0aa95cbda16ac88e4b4a0eb7d/ml/sk/feature_extraction/text.py#L21)

Comment: @tdelaney: Although it doesn’t look like it, that’s what the link points to.

Answer (score -1):

ut ["universal toolkit"](https://pypi.org/project/ut/). Have you tried to `pip install ut` That will install ut.

Comment: That package only has yaml/json conversion, not anything ml-related like in OP's import statement.

Comment: Are you referring to `https://pypi.org/project/ut/#files`? That looks like a very thin wrapper for some yaml stuff and not something that would have a `ut.ml.sk.feature_extraction.text`. It may just be something with the same name.